# SELECT variable como campo

Tags: php7

Necesito hacer una consulta con una variable como campo pero me da error. He probado con declare y set pero no me reconoce ninguna de las dos.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM fallos WHERE '".$block."' = '".$j."'");
```

Comment: Como ya sabes, editar y mostrar el error haría mas simple identificar que falla

Comment: $block."' lo uso para sustituir  4 campos en la tabla -->  block1 block2 ... y paso la variable $block por un for que cada vez que pasa toma el valor de los campos block1, block2... no puedo mostrar el error porque no hace nada en pantalla ni en consola como error. Lo que está fallando en la variable $block que la estoy usando como un campo de la tabla. Cuando lo sustituyo por block1, por ejemplo, funciona bien

Comment: vale, lo conseguí... hay que poner la variable entre llaves tal que así {$block}

Comment: Y si de paso mejoras la seguridad de tus consultas y te evitas esa sintaxis con consultas preparadas?

Comment: No sabría mejorarla... no soy experto en php y no estoy lucho para identificar dichas consultas @BetaM